# commandline agument to expand jdbc timeout

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have to maintain java code that is timing out with a sql call.  The error is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 7706,043 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent succesfully to the server was 2 milliseconds ago.
```

I think the program is doing as it should.  It actually takes 2 hours to process the full return value from the sql call!  I've already written a patch which would fix the timeout issue, and other issues, but it would be a month before we can release it to the production servers.

In the meantime is there a way I can configure the JDBC to use a longer timeout window?  I can't touch the code, but is there any way I can use either properties files or a command-line argument to configure the default JDBC timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by updating the URL that is used to connect to SQL.  The exact arguments used to expand the URL depend on which DB is connected to, but this webpage presents them in detail:

http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jdbc-internals-and-timeout-configuration/

Here is a copy of the relevant facts;

mysql: jdbc:mysql://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/database?connectTimeout=60000&socketTimeout=60000 (in ms)
mysql (jtds) jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:port/database;loginTimeout=60;socketTimeout=60  (in sec)